# Pass an id to a modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a table with some products,

```html
<td id="detail_maintenance_{{result.id}}" data-detail="" width="25px">
    <span id = "maintenaceDetail" data-maintenaceDetail="{{ result.id }}">
        {{result.id}}
        <i class="icon-search icon_loupe"></i>
    </span>
</td>
```

I'd like to open a modal with information = idModal when I click on the button icon-search,
the result id show me the ID i want,
but i'm trying to open a modal with the corresponding id (sorry for my english)
This is how i open the modal with jQuery :

```js
$('#modifierlaMnt').click(function () {
    ModifMaintenance();
    $('#validerLaMnt').show();
});
```

The problem is that modal opened but i can't modify the information because all modals have same information, that's why I'd like to open a modal id = {{result.id}} but I don't know how process.

Comment: How did you add all the modals? You've added them directly in your html for each product?

Comment: can you add `modifierlaMnt` button and is it getting repeated for each result id? Also post `ModifMaintenance` function (at least with relevant code)

Comment: @DarkBee
There is 1 modal in my HTML code, and i woudlike to change his ID when i click on his line on the table.
to show more details of this line

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, edited, good luck :p

Comment: Well first of you are looping products, but u've added an id `maintenaceDetail` which can't be done (as id's need to be unique), also I'd suggest moving the `data-maintenaceDetail` attribute to the `i` element and place a click handler on that, this way u can easily access the `id` and do wathever

Comment: Thanks you, and if i want to display product's informations , i have to use data-name, data-price ...?

Comment: Well sure, but maybe use an ajax request to update the modal view

Comment: ok, i can't put " this Answer is usefull" but it is,
Have a good day ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the data attribute `maintenaceDetail` to the element you want to click on, after that u can assign a click event of the element and have easy access to the data attribute, e.g.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'i.icon-search', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('maintenacedetail'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="detail_maintenance_{{result.id}}" data-detail="" width="25px">
      <span>
        foo <i class="icon-search icon_loupe" data-maintenacedetail="foo">O</i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="detail_maintenance_{{result.id}}" data-detail="" width="25px">
      <span>
        bar <i class="icon-search icon_loupe" data-maintenacedetail="bar">O</i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="detail_maintenance_{{result.id}}" data-detail="" width="25px">
      <span>
        foobar <i class="icon-search icon_loupe" data-maintenacedetail="foobar">O</i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="detail_maintenance_{{result.id}}" data-detail="" width="25px">
      <span>
        42 <i class="icon-search icon_loupe" data-maintenacedetail="42">O</i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```